# Typescript 2.0 module not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I used a visual studio asp core angular 2  starter template form here .

The template uses webpack as module loader.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/31a3eab5-e62b-4030-9226-b5e4c9e1ffb5

Now I created a project with this template (can be found [here](https://github.com/Gentlehag/Angular2KitchenSink)).

In VS Code everything is fine. but when i open the typescript files i can see that some TypeScript are not understood. For example in the code below `module` cannot be resolved
[image]

```
import 'angular2-universal-polyfills/browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformUniversalDynamic } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import 'bootstrap';

// Enable either Hot Module Reloading or production mode
if (module['hot']) {  //=>Cannot Resolve Moodule
    module['hot'].accept();
    module['hot'].dispose(() => { platform.destroy(); });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

I also tried installing typings with this command

```
npm install --save @types/node
npm install --save @types/lodash
```

The tsconfig (placed in the javascript app folder) looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "node" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you get the nuget package for Typescript 2.0 for VS?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/09/22/announcing-typescript-2-0/

Comment: yes i installed it.